# can I make a function into a variable to reduce my code (JavaScript Code debug Please)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I have been boggling my mind over and over again trying to simplify this java Script Code.

I am fairly new to JavaScript and I do not know where else to turn. 
I am making a navigation that when I click on a button it will animate to `transform:translateX(0);` from `transform:translateX(-98%);` as a class.

I am also making it if you hover over the div `.main-navigation` it will slide back and forth accordingly. I have it where the `mouseover` will slide the navigation if its open to the close state but I cannot do so when it is closed to open. I am also trying to make it if the `.home` is active then the hover will not open or close the `.home` just the menu.

Any suggestions?

```
$(function(){
    var navToggle = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-toggle');
    var mainMenu = document.querySelectorAll('.main-navigation');

    $(navToggle).on('click', function(){
        if ($(mainMenu).hasClass('close')){
            $(mainMenu).removeClass('close');
            $(mainMenu).addClass('open');
        }else{
            $(mainMenu).addClass('close');
            $(mainMenu).removeClass('open');
        };
        $('.home').toggleClass('hide, toggleAnimate');
        $('.contentWrap').toggleClass('open');
    });

    $(mainMenu).on('mouseenter', function(){
        if ($(mainMenu).hasClass('close')){
            $(mainMenu).removeClass('close');
            $(mainMenu).addClass('open');
        }
        if ($(mainMenu).hasClass('open')){
            $(mainMenu).removeClass('open');
            $(mainMenu).addClass('close');
        };
    });
});
```

Sorry I created a Code Pen to show you a very close example of what I am trying to do and the behavior that is happening.

[My CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/mchlsull/pen/azpdwK)

Comment: you aren't isolating instances within your event handler. Show some html

Comment: (1) how is the markup? (2) I thought you were using `toggleClass` weren't you?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I figured it out, I went with JQuery and was able to achieve my goal. I ended up changing it to this.

```
$(function(){
homeAnimate();
menuAnimate();
menuAnimate2();
autoAnimateEnter();
autoAnimateExit();

function homeAnimate(){
    $('.nav-toggle').click(function () {
        $('.home').toggleClass('hide, toggleAnimate');
        $('.contentWrap').toggleClass('open');
    });
}

function menuAnimate(){
    $('.nav-toggle').click(function () {
        if ($('.main-navigation').hasClass('close')) {
                $('.main-navigation').addClass('close');
                $('.main-navigation').toggleClass('open');
        }
        if ($('.main-navigation').hasClass('open')) {
                $('.main-navigation').toggleClass('close');
                $('.main-navigation').toggleClass('open');
        }
    });
}

function menuAnimate2(){
    $('.nav-toggle-menu').click(function () {
        if ($('.main-navigation').hasClass('open')) {

        } else {
            $('.main-navigation').addClass('open');
            $('.main-navigation').removeClass('close');
        }
        $('.home').toggleClass('hide, toggleAnimate');
        $('.contentWrap').toggleClass('open');
    });
}

function autoAnimateEnter(){

    $('.main-navigation').mouseenter(function () {
        if ($('.main-navigation').hasClass('close')) {
            $('.main-navigation').removeClass('close');
            $('.main-navigation').addClass('open');
        } else {
            // DO NOTHING
        }
    });
}

function autoAnimateExit(){

    $('.main-navigation').mouseleave(function () {
        if ($('.home').hasClass('toggleAnimate')) {
            // DO NOTHING
        } else {
            $('.main-navigation').removeClass('open');
            $('.main-navigation').addClass('close');
        }
    });
}
```

});

I'm not sure if this is the cleanest way in order to achieve my goal but it works and I'm happy.

Here is my code if anyone wants to check it out.
[Code](http://codepen.io/mchlsull/pen/azpdwK)